# How to avoid typing "this." before all class members in Typescript?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, typescript

I'm a lazy coder and I want a way to avoid typing "this." before all my class members. It is really boring to type the same 5 letters sequence several times in the same line like in :

```
this.A = this.condtion ? this.B : this.C;
```

A way would be to create a shortcut on a key that I never use like ² or ù (french keyboard). The editor would replace this char by "this." like autocorrect does for some typo in Word. Is there such feature in Visual Studio or Resharper ?

Comment: Really don't see why this question deserves minus votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying some spellchecker addons I finally use a AutoHotKey script.

This line in the script does what I want with ~ key (under ESC)

```
 :*:~::this.
```

It is very convenient. Simply press ~ key and it type "this." then the autocomplete appears. It is still possible to type ~ if it is typed right after an alphanumeric character.

Note : In fact I use the ² key on french AZERTY keyboard layout. Can someone confirm that ~ works the same on QWERTY ?

I'm still looking for a Visual Studio plugin that does this.